# How to send an email with rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer

This is probably very straight forward and simple, but I'm very new and noob at ruby on rails.
I have a simple email php script that I used on an older website, but now since I've converted to rails I'm not sure as to how to create the equivalent to that.

I tried using `rails generate mailer Notifier` and then inside of that added a welcome method which sent and email. However in the User controller (under create so that when a user made an account their email address was sent a welcome email) i just got an error that said Notifier wasn't declared.

In the user controller I had

```
if @user.save
  Notifier.welcome(@user).deliver
end
```

this did not work

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have been having the same problem, and apparently there is a need to use a SMTP server. I tried SendGrid, but it is also giving me errors. I would be so much nicer if rails behaved like PHP in some ways...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) could rescue you.

Comment: yeah +1 to you as well, RTMF rules! ;)

Comment: I read this but it didn't work. I put in my email and clicked create but I did not receive an email.
Can localhost send emails?

Comment: Did you look at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#example-action-mailer-configuration

Answer (score 6):

I suggest reading [Action Mailer Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)